# Sencha Touch 2 - Adding a textfield and updating its value

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

I have a rather easy issue I need a solution to. I've tried different options, but haven't got any good results. What I'm trying to do is, within a class, add a textfield and put a value via javascript in it.

For example, I got this code:

```
Ext.define('project.view.viewexample', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'gps',

config: {
    styleHtmlContent: true, 
    scrollabe: 'vertical',
    title: 'GPS',
    tpl: ''
},
constructor: function() {
    this.getPosition();
},
getPosition: function() {
    var geo = Ext.create('Ext.util.Geolocation', {
        autoUpdate: false,
        listeners: {
            locationupdate: function(geo) {
                alert('New latitude: ' + geo.getLatitude());
            },
            locationerror: function(geo, bTimeout, bPermissionDenied, bLocationUnavailable, message) {
                if(bTimeout){
                    alert('Timeout occurred.');
                } else {
                    alert('Error occurred.');
                }
            }
        }
    });
    geo.updateLocation();
}
});
```

What if I, want to create a textfield and instead of alerting the latitude-value updating the textfield with it. How would I do that?

1. How to create the textfield with the structure I use above?
2. How to call and modify it from the javascript?

Thanks in advance! Big cred to the one sitting on this knowledge!

Comment: instead of textfield, a popup or msgbox might be good.

Comment: yeah, you're right. However, I'm trying to learn how things are put together in ST2

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, instead of displaying message in textfield, a message box would be more appropriate. If you use sencha's msg box then you'll get a nice look too. So no need to use simple `alert`.

You can do this..

```
Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'Timeout has been occurred.', function(){
     // stuff to do when use clicks on Ok button. Can listen to location again.
});
```

Just replace this with `alert`.

Comment: I agree. A messagebox would be more suitable and Senchas own alert looks very neat. However, this is not what I'm looking for. I'm still gonna give you a thumbs up for the tip though, thank you :)

Comment: @Thomas If you could tell us what you are looking for then we could help more.

Comment: No offense, but I think I wrote it pretty clear in my original post. I like your comment and I also rated it one up for beeing a good tip. Because it really was. But it wasn't what I was asking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Create textfield with jQuery in your constructor

```
$("#form").append('Lat: <input id="latitude" type="text" name="latitude">');
```

Update textfield

```
$("#form").find("#latitude").val(geo.getLatitude());
```

That is it :)

Comment: how can you tell OP is using jQuery ??

Comment: I wasn't using JQuery actually. However I'm still glad you wrote, it was a good idea. I got the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" though.

Comment: you can easily inlcude jQuery into your project

Comment: You can easily include every JavaScript library and framework in existence, else accept that when jQuery isn't the one present, the one that is way well have all the tools available.

Answer (score 0):

You have the structure in place, including one of the multitude of means of creating what you want written - yet it is an empty string.

Something like this should work:

```
config: {
    styleHtmlContent: true, 
    scrollabe: 'vertical',
    title: 'GPS',
    lat: '',
    tpl: '<div class="lat">New latitude: {lat}</div>'
},
constructor: function() {
    this.getPosition();
},
getPosition: function() {
    var geo = Ext.create('Ext.util.Geolocation', {
        autoUpdate: false,
        listeners: {
            locationupdate: function(geo) {
                this.lat = geo.getLatitude();
            },
```

The class (lat) in the template offers a means of styling via css.

Other means really depends on how you want it displayed - textbox, titlebar, floating box, text, etc. Do you want it there all the time, or only on new input?

Instead of "tpl", have:

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'label',
    html: '',
    itemId: 'latLabel'
}]

// listener updater:
panel.down('#latLabel').setHtml('New latitude: ' + geo.getLatitude());
```

There are so many other means of creating precisely what you're after. The Sencha Touch library is rich in tools for creating and/or updating elements that specifically meet your needs.

Hope this helps.